# Converting float negative values to integer value in c launguage

Tags: c

I want to convert `float` negative values to `unsigned int` values. Is it possible?

For example:

```
float x = -10000.0;
int y;
y = x;
```

When we assign x value to y, can the negative value be stored in an integer?
If not, how can we store the negative values into integer variables?

Comment: It is unclear whether you are using `int` or `unsigned int`, or what unsigned value you expect `-10000.0` to be stored as. You can store `float` values in the range of the integer type you are using.

Comment: Your first sentence says you want to store values in an `unsigned int`. The code you show to demonstrate this stores a value in an `int`. That is not an example of storing a value in an `unsigned int`. So your question is inconsistent and unclear. Edit it to talk about only `unsigned int` or only `int`. In any case, an `unsigned int` will never hold a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

> can the negative (`float f`) value be stored in an integer?

Yes, with limitations.

---

With a *signed* integer type like `int16_t i`, `i = f` is well defined for

```
-32768.999... to 32767.999...
```

With an *unsigned* integer type like `unt16_t u`, `u = f` is well defined for

```
-0.999... to 65535.999...
```

The result is a truncated value (fraction thrown away).  All other `float` values result in *undefined behavior*.

> If not, how can we store the negative values into integer variables?

Best to use wide *signed* integer types and test for range limitations.

In any case, **the fraction of the `float` is lost**.  A `-0.5f` can be stored in an `unsigned`, yet the value becomes `0u`.

---

The below performs some simply tests to insure `y` is in range.

```
#include <limits.h>
float x = ...;
int y = 0;

if (x >= INT_MAX + 1u) puts("Too pos");
else if (x <= INT_MIN - 1.0) puts("Too neg");
else y = (int) x;
```

---

**Note** the  tests above are illustrative as they lack high portability.

Example: `INT_MIN - 1.0` in inexact in select situations.

To cope, with common 2's complement `int`, the below is better reformed.  As 2's complement, `INT_MIN` is a power of 2 (negated) and usually in the range of `float`, thus making for an exact subtraction near the negative threshold.  `

```
// if (x <= INT_MIN - 1.0)
if (x - INT_MIN <= - 1.0f)
```

---

Another alternative is to explore a `union`.  Leave that for others to explain its possibilities and limitations.

```
union {
  float f;
  unsigned u;
} x;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
float x = 10000.0;
int a;

a = (int)(x+0.5);
```

Comment: Why `x+0.5`?  Note `(int)(x+0.5)` does not round to nearest when `x < 0`.